# Javascript code only works when Empty Cache and Hard Reload

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, caching, woocommerce

I'm adding javascript code to a woocommerce wordpress website.

The code is simple. What does is, when the user clicks on a div area of the checkout page, the code makes it click on the submit button as well.

What I did was add this code php to my functions.php file:

```
add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "jm_insertar_js3");
    function jm_insertar_js3(){
        if (is_checkout()){
            wp_register_script('miscript3', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/script3.js', array('jquery'), microtime(true), true );
            wp_enqueue_script('miscript3');
        }
    }
```

And then, I created this file (script3.js):

```
window.onload = function(){
    var div3 = document.querySelectorAll('div.mp-row-checkout');
    for (var i = 0; i < div3.length; i++) {
        div3[i].onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById("place_order").click();
        }
    }
}
```

In fact, when I try this code in the browser console:

```
    var div3 = document.querySelectorAll('div.mp-row-checkout');
    for (var i = 0; i < div3.length; i++) {
        div3[i].onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById("place_order").click();
        }
    }
```

Everything works perfectly.

The problem is that when I try the code normally nothing happens (when I click the div area the code don't run), and I have to Empty Cache and Hard Reload to make it works. I just don't know why or how can I fix this.

I disable all type of cache server-side and website-side. I'm doing the test from an incognito tab to avoid cache. And finally, I add a timestamp (microtime(true)) to the version of the file to avoid browsers from caching and the issue still persist.

I'm not a programmer, so any information will help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is this happening in all browsers? I feel like this could be a security feature to avoid clickjacking. Can you check what function is executed on "place_order" click and execute that directly?

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply.

I have problems with firefox too, but in that case, even without refreshing the page works.

place_order is a button that submits the form (checkout) and redirects to the payment gateway page.

Sorry, Am I answering your question? I' am new at this.

Comment: Partially :) What I meant: As an example (I know you said it makes the submit): if the button click runs a js function `myClick()` instead of calling `document.getElementById("place_order").click();` you could directly call myClick(). So in your case make the submit of the form directly. Just run `document.yourForm.submit();` where yourform is the `name` attribute of the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to change the trigger event. window.onload generates issues.

Final JS file (script3.js):

```
var div3 = document.querySelectorAll('div.woocommerce-billing-fields, input.input-text ');
for (var i = 0; i < div3.length; i++) {
    div3[i].onclick = function() {
        var idNuevo = document.getElementById("jm-mp-row-checkout");
        if (!idNuevo) {
            document.getElementsByClassName("mp-row-checkout")[0].setAttribute("id", "jm-mp-row-checkout");
            document.getElementById("jm-mp-row-checkout").addEventListener("click", myFunctionJM2);
            function myFunctionJM2() {
                document.getElementById("place_order").click();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For preventing from browser cache for js file. We can add a query string. like

/script3.js?qid=currentTimeStamp

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply.

I did so, in this line:

`wp_register_script('miscript3', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/script3.js', array('jquery'), microtime(true), true );`

**microtime(true)**

But the problem still persist.

Comment: it's just a suggestion. try to add your code to the below event instated of onload. 

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    // Your Code
});